React not rendering alert when confirming comment deletion in modal
Context: interactive comment section CRUD app
When deleting a comment, the user clicks a Delete button which opens a modal to ask them to confirm the deletion. That part (the modal opening/closing and deleting the comment) works fine.
What I want to add is an alert/flash notification once the user has confirmed the deletion and the comment is removed. I was able to implement this when updating the comment, but when using the exact same method for deleting, the alert is not rendering for some reason.
I have a feeling this has something to do with the fact that this component uses a modal but I can't figure out what is blocking exactly.
What I've tried:

setting the alert state and the showAlert function directly in the DeleteConfirmationModal (as opposed to passing it down from a parent component)
placing {alert.show && <Alert {...alert} showAlert={showAlert} />} inside the Modal or inside the article
forcing the modal to stay open (for debugging purposes)
giving a high z-index to the Alert aside element
using React portals to render the alert outside the modal’s DOM hierarchy

Here below is my code. I would be grateful if someone could help me fixing this.
const UserActionButtons = ({ comment, isEditing, isMobile, isReply, isCurrentUser, onDelete, editComment, handleClickReply}: UserActionButtonsProps) => {
    const [isDeleteModalOpen, setDeleteModalOpen] = useState<boolean>(false)

    const handleOpenConfirmationModal = (): void => {
        setDeleteModalOpen(true)
    }

    const handleCloseConfirmationModal = (): void => {
        setDeleteModalOpen(false)
    }

    return (
        <>
            {isCurrentUser ?
                (<div className={`${isEditing && isMobile ? 'hidden' : 'cta-button'}`}>
                    <div className='flex items-center fill-primary-red-soft hover:fill-primary-red-pale   text-primary-red-soft hover:text-primary-red-pale  '>
                        <DeleteIcon />
                        <p className="font-medium mr-4"
                            onClick={() => handleOpenConfirmationModal()}
                        >  Delete</p>
                    </div>
                    <DeleteConfirmationModal
                        isOpen={isDeleteModalOpen}
                        onDelete={onDelete}
                        onCancel={handleCloseConfirmationModal}
                        comment={comment}
                        isReply={isReply}
                    />
                    <div className='flex items-center cta-button-blue'>
                        <EditIcon />
                        <p className="font-medium"
                            onClick={editComment}
                        >  Edit</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                ) : !isEditing &&
                (<div className='cta-button cta-button-blue'>
                    <ReplyIcon />
                    <p className="font-medium"
                        onClick={handleClickReply}
                    >  Reply</p>
                </div>)}
        </>
    )
}

const DeleteConfirmationModal = ({
    isOpen,
    comment,
    isReply,
    onCancel,
    onDelete
}: DeleteConfirmationModalProps) => {
    const { id } = comment
    const [alert, setAlert] = useState<AlertInterface>({ show: false, type: '', text: '' })

    const showAlert = (show = false, type = '', text = ''): void => {
        setAlert({ show, type, text })
    }

    const deleteComment = (id: number, deletedComment?: MessageMeta): void => {
        onDelete(id, deletedComment)
        showAlert(true, 'success', 'Comment deleted!')
        // console.log(alert.show)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(alert)
    }, [alert])

    return (
        <>
            {alert.show && <Alert {...alert} showAlert={showAlert} />}
            <Modal isOpen={isOpen}>
                <article className='flex flex-col gap-y-4'>
                    <h4 className='font-medium text-xl text-neutral-blue-dark'>Delete comment</h4>
                    <p className='text-neutral-blue-grayish'>Are you sure you want to delete this comment? This will remove the comment and can't be undone.</p>
                    <div className='flex gap-x-2 justify-between'>
                        <button className='bg-neutral-blue-grayish text-white font-medium px-4 sm:px-8 py-3 uppercase rounded-lg border-none w-6/12'
                            onClick={onCancel}>No, cancel</button>
                        <button className='bg-primary-red-soft text-white font-medium px-4 sm:px-8 py-3 uppercase rounded-lg border-none w-6/12'
                            onClick={() => deleteComment(id, isReply ? comment : undefined)}
                        >Yes, delete</button>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </Modal >
        </>
    )
}

const Alert = ({
    type,
    text,
    showAlert
}: AlertProps) => {

    console.log('alert renders')

    useEffect(() => {
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            showAlert()
        }, 3000)
        return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
    }, [])

    return (
        <aside className={`${type === 'success' ? 'bg-primary-green-success' : 'bg-primary-red-soft'} text-white fixed bottom-5 right-5 p-4 z-50`}>{text}</aside>
    )
}

const Modal = ({
    isOpen,
    children
}: ModalProps) => {
    const [isModalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(isOpen)
    const modalRef = useRef<HTMLDialogElement | null>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        setModalOpen(isOpen)
    }, [isOpen])

    useEffect(() => {
        const modalElement = modalRef.current

        if (modalElement) {
            if (isModalOpen) {
                modalElement.showModal()
            } else {
                modalElement.close()
            }
        }
    }, [isModalOpen])

    return (
        <dialog ref={modalRef}
            className={'p-4 sm:p-6 rounded-lg min-w-20 max-w-xs sm:max-w-sm cursor-default'}>
            {children}
        </dialog>
    )
}


What’s the component that wraps UserActionButtons? My guess would be that after onDelete is called, none of this is rendered at all, because the item that the buttons were contained within is gone now.

The solution would be to move the handling for the alert to its parent component (the parent of all of the comments that are displayed).

@TimMoore Lifting the state up was indeed part of the solution (as I realised it was also not working when alerting that a comment was successfully submitted for example). And I also needed to add a prop to the Comment component (which I didn't share here). A bit hard to sum up the solution but it works now. Thanks for your input though!

I actually found the solution which is not in the code I shared above
Basically because I'm recursively rendering the comments, I also needed to pass the showAlert prop to the Comment component itself
I also lifted the state up to the highest parent
 {comment.replies?.length !== 0 ? (
            <div className='flex w-full'>
                <div className='w-0.5 bg-neutral-gray-light md:ml-12'></div>
                <div className='pl-6 md:pl-12 max-w-full flex-grow'>
                    {comment.replies?.map((reply) =>
                    (<Comment
                        key={reply.id}
                        comment={reply}
                        currentUser={currentUser}
                        commentList={commentList}
                        onReply={onReply}
                        onEdit={onEdit}
                        onDelete={onDelete}
                        onScoreChange={onScoreChange}
                        showAlert={showAlert}
                    />))}
                </div>
            </div>) : null}

